# Конструкция try except удаляет мою переменную. Зачем?

Tags: python, исключения

Вот код

```
ex_value = ''
try:
    2/0
except ValueError as ex_value:
    print(ex_value)
except ZeroDivisionError as ex_value:
    print(ex_value)
finally:
    print(ex_value)
```

Вот печать в терминале

```
division by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Vasil\anaconda3\envs\AMZ\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "d:\onedrive\projects\chud_amaz\soft_in_dev\moduled_way_oop\code_questions\try_except_var_in_finally.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(ex_value)

NameError: name 'ex_value' is not defined
```

Как распечатать в finally  сообщение и зачем **try** удаляет мою переменную **ex_value**.

Comment: На днях был похожий вопрос, помню )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Зачем try удаляет мою переменную ex_value

Как уже ответил @Danis, это происходит, потому что все объекты исключений, созданные внутри блока `try-except` (и также сохраненные в переменные оператором `as`), очищаются при завершении блоков.

> Как распечатать в finally сообщение

Не совсем понимаю зачем это может быть нужно, но в принципе достаточно сохранять объект исключения в другой переменной, из которой потом его и выводить.

```
try:
    2/0
except ValueError as z:
    print(ex_value := z)
except ZeroDivisionError as z:
    print(ex_value := z)
finally:
    print(ex_value)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> division by zero
> division by zero
> ```

Comment: Мне нужно знать какое нестандартное исключение случилось.

Answer (score 2):

Из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html):

> Exceptions are cleared
> because with the traceback attached to them, they form a reference
> cycle with the stack frame, keeping all locals in that frame alive
> until the next garbage collection occurs.

Comment: У нас тут как-бы SO на русском ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Так вы назвали ошибку именем переменной, смените обзывание ошибки другим именем:

```
ex_value = ''
try:
    2/0
except ValueError as ve:
    print(ex_value)
except ZeroDivisionError as zde:
    print(ex_value)
finally:
    print(ex_value)
```

Comment: мне как раз и надо распечатать zde.